# Material UI Autocomplete getOptionSelected Comparison Discrepancy Between Hardcoded Options Versus State

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have this [Material UI Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) Component and whenever I select an item,
(1) its value gets set to the state. (2) When it gets selected, it should no longer appear as an option on the Autocomplete component.

However, take a look at the `options` prop I passed to the Autocomplete component. You will notice that I have 2 of them, and 1 of them is commented out. The issue is: when I use the state based approach, my implementation works as expected (i.e., satisfying both requirement 1 and 2). However, when I do not use the state based approach and use the hardcoded array, the equality checking seems to fail on the `handleGetOptionSelected` method.

Note that I already have a solution to this by just checking the `language`. I am more interested in acquiring knowledge as to why this is happening.

```
const handleGetOptionSelected = (option, value) => {
  return option.language === value.language;
}; /* I already know about this */
```

**I am interested in knowing why it fails** when using the hardcoded approach versus the state based approach. So **my question**: Why is it that the comparison here fails when using hardcoded array versus the state based array?

State based array logs:
[image]

Hardcoded array logs:
[image]

```
options={[{ language: "C" }, { language: "C#" }, { language: "C++" }]} // this causes error in equality checking

options={availableLanguages} // this approach works fine
```

---

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { Autocomplete } from "@material-ui/lab";

export default function App() {
  const [languages, setLanguages] = useState([]);

  const [availableLanguages] = useState([
    { language: "C" },
    { language: "C#" },
    { language: "C++" }
  ]);

  const handleGetOptionSelected = (option, value) => {
    console.log(`option`, option);
    console.log(`value`, value);
    console.log(`is equal`, option === value);
    return option === value;
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Selected Languages</h1>
      <hr />
      {languages.map((item, index) => (
        <p key={index}>{item.language}</p>
      ))}
      <hr />
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        name="ClassSchedule"
        filterSelectedOptions
        getOptionSelected={(option, value) =>
          handleGetOptionSelected(option, value)
        }
        onChange={(event, value) => setLanguages(value)}
        ChipProps={{
          style: {
            backgroundColor: "#2EC5B6",
            borderRadius: "5px",
            color: "#fff",
            fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro"
          }
        }}
        id="tags-standard"

        options={[
          { language: "C" }, 
          { language: "C#" }, 
          { language: "C++" }
        ]} // this causes error in equality checking

        // options={availableLanguages} // this approach works fine

        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.language}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            style={{
              borderRadius: "10px",
              backgroundColor: "#F5FCFB",
              fontFamily: "Source Sans Pro"
            }}
            variant="outlined"
            id="custom-css-outlined-input"
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/so-material-ui-autocomplete-question-gen4q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: object comparison is a reference comparison, creating the array inline `options={[{ language: "C" }, { language: "C#" }, { language: "C++" }]}` causes new objects with new references to be created each time the component renders. Using state to store the array, the objects are only changed when you change them (Although seeing you are never using the set of the available languages useState you could instead use useMemo).

Comment: Interesting... are you able to elaborate perhaps in a Vanilla JS example? I am more of a visual learner

Comment: The MDN has a short Comparing Objects section in the [Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) page. For a bit of an example of the difference between the two I created a basic React example and outlined very roughly what is occurring. You can look at the comments / the notes written to the view as well as further reading from the MDN / other resources to get a hold on what is happening: [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qgmvgf).

Comment: Kudos to you @JacobSmit. I appreciate it! The same logic applies in the Component I have shared in my question.